# No change in the original values of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, pandas-groupby

I have a sample dataframe `df` as follows -

```
A  B
1  41
2  42
3  43
1  46
2  47
3  48
1  51
2  52
3  53
```

My current objective is that, for a particular value of column A, replace all the values of column B by the first occurence. For example, for A = 1, B = 41 is the first corresponding value. So, I have to replace all other rows with A = 1 for B column as 41. Basically, I have to obtain the following:

```
A  B
1  41
2  42
3  43
1  41
2  42
3  43
1  41
2  42
3  43
```

I have tried to proceed as follows:

**METHOD 1 -**

```
a = df.A.unique()
for i in a:
    x = df.loc[df['A'] == i]
    x['B'] = x['B'].iloc[0]
    print(x)
```

On printing `x`, this gives me the desired output as

```
    A   B
0   1  41
3   1  41
6   1  41
    A   B
1   2  42
4   2  42
7   2  42
    A   B
2   3  43
5   3  43
8   3  43
```

But when I check the dataframe `df` again, there is **absolutely no change in the values.**

I also tried the following alternative -

**METHOD - 2**

```
def custom_function(df):
    x = df['B'].iloc[0]
    df['A'] = df['A']
    df.loc[:,['B']] = x
    return df['A']

for key, item in df.groupby('A'):
    item.apply(lambda x: custom_function(item))
    print(item)
```

On printing `item`, this also gave me the desired output as -

```
    A   B
0   1  41
3   1  41
6   1  41
    A   B
1   2  42
4   2  42
7   2  42
    A   B
2   3  43
5   3  43
8   3  43
```

But when I check the value of dataframe `df`, there are **no modifications** at all. I am guessing that I am working on a copy of the dataframe rather than the actual dataframe but I am at a loss as to how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're creating a new variable inside a loop with a shallow copy of the data and modifying that. Changes to the original dataframe are not actually written unless you do it yourself with `df.loc`. Another, better option is to vectorise this, removing the loop.

You'll need `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df = df.assign(B=df.groupby('A').B.transform('first')).sort_values('A')
print(df)
   A   B
0  1  41
3  1  41
6  1  41
1  2  42
4  2  42
7  2  42
2  3  43
5  3  43
8  3  43
```

---

For your understanding only, this is how to fix your loop:

```
for a in df.A.unique():
    m = df['A'] == a 
    df.loc[m, 'B'] = df.at[m.idxmax(), 'B']
```